# Firefox text gradient

Tags: firefox, css

I was wondering if there is a way to apply a text gradient in Firefox? I can get it to work in Chrome and Safari and the code goes like:

```css
h1 {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#000000));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 4em "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

But there doesn't seem to be anything out there for Mozilla.

Comment: Hi, 
How did you fix this in the end?

Comment: Now supported, btw..

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I think only WebKit-based browsers implement the `text-fill-color` property. As far as I'm aware, there is no workaround for Mozilla yet.

Comment: I think your right I also tried:  
-moz-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
color: transparent;

didn't work either, booo (shakes fist at Firefox)

Answer (score 1):

FireFox does now appear to support the webkit parameters, aliasing `-webkit-background-clip` as `background-clip` (webkit doesn't alias it, hence the most compatible way at present appears to be to use -webkit-backgroup-clip as both FF and WK understand it)

[image]

Comment: This is backed up by [the MDN background-clip page](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip), which includes an example; and seems to indeed work in practice.